# Formatting large amounts of differently structured ascii text snippets into a uniform format

Tags: html, text-processing

we need a software recommendation for the task of formatting large amounts of differently structured ascii text snippets into a uniform format that looks good in html.
The text snippets can be plain text and enumerations with different bullet items, different spacings, tabs, etc. 
They can also contain tables drawn from asci characters like ********** and |    |       |      | and so on.
We have attached two example files resembling the “Is” and the “Should” state, but there are a LOT of different scenarios how the “Is” state can be formatted. 
Ideally the output html should be flexible for different resolutions and devices, e.g. tablets, mobiles.
Is there any kind of software or tool that can do such a thing? Or do you have any recommendations how this process can be automated instead of modifying the texts by hand?

Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have seen this question before. Did you post it elsewhere/earlier?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=ocr+tables+is%3Aq

Comment: I will check for suitable OCR Software. Once i have tested it i ll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Hey Jan, i have tried a few but unfortunately it didnt solve the problem. Do you have any other recommendation

Comment: Please [edit] your question saying which specific OCR packages you tried; so that others know they don't have to suggest those.